# Disable click on external monitor to activate it

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I am using 2 external monitors with my MacBook Pro. When I move my pointer to a different screen, I have to click on it first to activate it, then proceed with what I want to do.
Is there a way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is inherent to the macOS paradigm, & opposite to Windows behaviour.

The first click is to activate [bring to the front] the chosen app or window without performing any accidental clicks within it. Windows chose to do it the other way round, the first click can also perform an action.
I've often thought each of these choices is simply what you get used to and the opposite is irritating;)

There are *some* functions that can be done without activating first - if you hover over the red/yellow/green dots of a backgrounded window you will see they highlight & can be actioned directly, but generally this should not happen.

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought it can be disabled but it turned out to be a macOS paradigm. Thank you for clearing that up.